# Play store downloaded more than 100%

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android

[image]

What is happening? Play store keeps downloading after 100% how to fix this ?

Comment: I had a similar problem on a very old version of the Google Play Store. Did you try pressing "Force Stop"?